# Sharing wired Internet connection as Wireless?

Tags: windows, networking, wireless-networking, router

I'm running Windows 8.1 on my Samsung Laptop with Motherboard / model: NP-530U3C.

It's connected to the internet with a wire, and I saw this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Nh6gbrnYzS0) which says there's an option to share the connection as a wirlesss one, so I can turn my laptop to a Wifi hot spot.

However, in my Ethernet sharing properties, I don't have any wirless sharing option (As opposed to that shown in the tutorial):

[image]

Does it mean my laptop is missing a necessary hardware (even though it's from 2013)? or this can be solved somehow software-wise?

Comment: [Share your internet connection via WiFi on Windows 8.1](http://www.marcusoft.net/2014/01/share-your-internet-connection-via-wifi.html)

Comment: Doesn't work, even with the .bat file I'm still not seeing any scroll-down options under the "sharing" tab.

Comment: Did you check the Problems section re `adhoc` support?

Comment: I don't even have an "advanced" tab under my Wi-Fi adapter properties, so I can't see anything about `adhoc`.

Comment: You might have to click `Configure` first ... Try right click `Properties` -> `Configure` button -> `Advanced` tab. You should see `AdHoc` under `Properties`

Comment: Yeah in that menu though I only see: `ad hoq QqS mode` (set to WMM disabled, changing to enabled didn't make a difference) and `ad ho channel 802 (set to 11).

Comment: Sorry, no other ideas.